# Internet drops whenever I play a steam game

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, internet-connection, steam

I'm having this weird issue on my new Laptop. Whenever I play a Steam game that's connected to the internet (e.g. Rocket League or Slay The Spire with Twitch Integration enabled) my internet seems to drop below 1 Mbit/s up and down. This seems to only affect my Laptop though. The Internet connection for e.g. my Phone is still stable. I'm using WiFi for both.
This seems to happen only for games I bought on Steam. However, I don't have to start them through Steam for my internet to drop. E.g. Starting Slay The Spire through the jar with Twitch Integration enabled also causes the internet to drop. If Twitch Integration is disabled, no drop happens.

Also testing with MoonLighter yielded the following result: Starting the game normally causes the internet to drop. However, if I  block the Game in the Windows Firewall, the internet connection is unaffected if I open the game.

Speedtest on my Laptop with no Steam game open:
http://prntscr.com/k0j4p3
(26.7 Mbit/s down / 9.01 Mbit/s up)

Speedtest with RocketLeague open (Only in the Main Menu without joining a game):
https://prnt.sc/k0j9rq (0.53 Mbit/s down / 0.20 Mbit/s up)

After googling a bit I found [this tip](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/528398719812567007/) that states turning off flow control is a potential fix. This did not work for me.

My Laptop has two different Network adapters: Intel (R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 and Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

If anyone knows a way to fix this or why it is happening please speak up. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So which adapter are you actually using on the laptop?  Only one is in use at a time.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry I'm a bit of Noob. How can I figure out which one I'm using? I thought one of these devices is for WiFi and one is for LAN and the statement I am using WiFi would help.

Comment: The two adapters you specified are "Wireless" and "Ethernet" respectively- Ethernet connections override Wireless so, if you have Ethernet plugged in, you're wired (unless you disable the Ethernet NIC), if you don't, you're wireless.

Comment: Well I don't have any Ethernet plugged in. I'm just using WiFi

Comment: Have you updated the drivers for the Intel wlan card? And are you using Windows or the device manufacturer network manager?

Comment: The Drivers are all up to date and I'm using Windows Device Manager